# Checking if a number is a power of 2 without loops

Tags: c, bitwise

I made a short program which checks if a number is a power of 2 without using any loops.
The idea: A number which is a power of 2 must have only one bit "1" ( ex: 8= 1000, 4=100 and so on). 
Suppose we have a power of 2:nr = 10...000 (in binary), if we subtract 1 we will get something like this:nr-1= 01...111. Now, if we do nr&(nr-1) we should always get 0 if the nr is a power of 2 and some random number if it isn't. What other solutions are there for this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int nr;
    scanf("%d",&nr);
    if((nr&(nr-1))==0)
    {
        printf("\n%d is a power of 2",nr);
    }
    else
    {
         printf("\n%d is not a power of 2",nr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but i'm not checking if a number is divisible by 2, i'm checking if a number is a power of 2. what do you mean?

Comment: CPUs have a "population count" instruction built in.  Compilers often provide access to it via an intrinsic.  So `return ++popcnt(nr)==1;` is all you need.

Comment: For related bit-fiddling tricks, see the book "Hacker's Delight".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What other solutions are there for this problem?

OP's code can incorrectly reports 0 and -2147483648 (`INT_MIN`) are both powers-of 2.

A simple change is to use `unsigned` rather than `int` [@Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight).  This avoids 1) the corner case of `INT_MIN - 1` which is *undefined behavior* and 2) and-ing a negative `int`, which is *implementation defined behavior*.

```
unsigned nr;
scanf("%u",&nr);
if ((nr & (nr-1)) == 0 && nr)
```

Answer (score 10):

- Use only necessary `#include`s. The `<stdlib.h>` is not needed here.
- Give your operators some breathing space. `((nr&(nr-1))==0)` is next to unreadable.
- Separate logic from presentation:

  ```
  int is_power_of_two(int nr)
  {
      return nr & (nr - 1) == 0;
  }
  ```

  is much more reusable.
- Care about corner cases. Your code claims that `0` *is* a power of two (which it is not).

Comment: Probably ought to add a few negative numbers to the test suite of corner cases - or (better) change `nr` to an unsigned type.